# Ошибка в RedBean PHP

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Когда нажимаю на кнопку выдает ошибку

```
<?php
require "db.php";
$data = $_POST;
if (isset($data['changelogin'])) {
$errors = array();

if (trim($data['oldlogin']) == '') {
    $errors[] = 'Введите старый логин';
}

if (trim($data['oldlogin']) != $_SESSION['logged_user']->name) {
    $errors[] = 'Не правильный старый логин';
}

if (trim($data['newlogin']) == '') {
    $errors[] = 'Введите новый логин';
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $user = R::find('users', 'name = ?', array($data['oldlogin']));
    (line 21)$user->name = $data['newlogin'];
    R::store($user);
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    echo '<div style="color: red;">' . array_shift($errors) . '</div>';
}
} ?>
```

Хочу чтоб при нажатии на кнопку менялся логин пользователя но выдает ошибку Аttempt to assign property 'name' of non-object in in C:\xampp\htdocs\registernew\change-login.php on line 21
(line 21) это вы уже поняли что линия 21

Comment: мы должны сами придумать какую ошибку?

Comment: `$user` видимо пусто? ваш запрос в предыдущей строке возвращает пустой результат?

Comment: но он не может возвращать пустой результат

Comment: @TarasOsyka, Давайте перейдем в чат?

Comment: ребят спасибо большое что выделили своё время. Я уже решил проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ребят спасибо большое что выделили своё время. Я уже решил проблему

```
    $id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
    $user = R::load('users', $id);
    $user->name = $data['newlogin'];
    R::store($user);
    header('Location: logout.php');
```

Я загружаю ID и меняю имя человека так